# Javascript - What is the function of Curly Brackets { } without a declaration?

Tags: javascript

When a piece of code has `{` `}` without any sort of declaration - what is it's function?

```
{
  ...code here...
}
```

Comment: It's a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

Comment: That creates an isolated scope.

Comment: That said, it's unusual to see and rarely necessary. Is there a particular piece of code that goes with this?

Comment: @jarmod Doesn't seem like there's a definite purpose to it. I'm following this tutorial: https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-game.html , it's in the first line of code. I found it unusual

Comment: It's being used to create a local scope so that `gltfLoader` doesn't become a global variable. Before ES6 this would be done with an IIFE.

Comment: There is a purpose to it when local variables are declared, which is to isolate them and [reduce their scope](https://refactoring.com/catalog/reduceScopeOfVariable.html) to the minimum possible, but it's uncommon outside of browsers (per Barmar's comment) imo. You typically get the same or similar effect by simply writing short functions, which in and of itself is valuable.

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys. How do I accept an answer though?